# python how do I empty or clear a zip()

Tags: python

`zip()` returns a list of tuples. I have a situation where I have to zip something,and empty `zip()`. How do I empty or clear what I have zipped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign it something different:

```
zipped = None
```

or

```
zipped = []
```

for an empty list.

Alternatively, slice assign an empty list:

```
zipped[:] = []
```

to remove all elements in the list `zipped` refers to.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign it to an empty list

```
zipped = []
```

or let it go out of scope. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: +1 for "What are you trying to accomplish?"

Answer (score 4):

If you have other references to the same list that you would like to be cleared as well, use slice assignment to empty this list but use the same object:

```
zipped[:] = []
```

Note that in most cases this is probably not necessary, and `zipped = []` or `zipped = None` will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Or use [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in place of `zip` so that `zipped` is exhausted after a single pass (assuming you are writing all of `zipped` to the CSV